# C# - Get exact data from excel without format

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read data from Excel.

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("/sample.xlsx");
Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets["Table 1"];

Range range = (Range)sheet.get_Range("A" + 1, "A" + 1);
String value = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[1].Value);
```

> Column A1 = "01" and my output is "1"

How to get raw data without format from this cell (my expected output is "01")? Also same question with column which has date format 'MM/dd/yy'.

Comment: Your code works for me if I format the cell to type "text" in excel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use text:

```
 String value = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[1].Text);
```

`.Text` gives you a string representing what is displayed on the screen for the cell. Using .Text is usually a bad idea because you could get ####

`.Value2` gives you the underlying value of the cell (could be empty, string, error, number (double) or boolean)

`.Value` gives you the same as .Value2 except if the cell was formatted as currency or date it gives you a VBA currency (which may truncate decimal places) or VBA date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the reader, Your Excel sheet must be having columns formatted as number. Please format your column to text column. if possible.

and for the columns formatted as date time, You can parse the date and format it the way you want refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]